# minikube dns does not resolve on host fedora systemd-resolve

Tags: domain-name-system, kubernetes, fedora, minikube, systemd-resolve

I have setup minikube with the docker driver, but the problem is the same with the virtualbox driver.

I'm on fedora 39 and i followed the explanation here:
https://minikube.sigs.k8s.io/docs/handbook/addons/ingress-dns/

```
nslookup hello-jane.test $(minikube ip)                         
Server:     192.168.49.2
Address:    192.168.49.2#53

Non-authoritative answer:
Name:   hello-jane.test
Address: 192.168.49.2
Name:   hello-jane.test
Address: 192.168.49.2
```

That works!

from within a container as well:

```
root@debian2:/# ping hello-jane.test
PING hello-jane.test (192.168.49.2) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 192-168-49-2.kubernetes.default.svc.cluster.local (192.168.49.2): icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=0.015 ms
```

however from the host, without specifying the cluster IP

```
nslookup hello-jane.test  
Server:     127.0.0.53
Address:    127.0.0.53#53

** server can't find hello-jane.test: NXDOMAIN
```

ofc the ping does not work.

I guess its because of the `systemd-resolve` which may interfer...

```
systemd-resolve --status                                                          
Global
         Protocols: LLMNR=resolve -mDNS -DNSOverTLS DNSSEC=no/unsupported
  resolv.conf mode: stub

Link 2 (enp0s31f6)
    Current Scopes: none
         Protocols: -DefaultRoute LLMNR=resolve -mDNS -DNSOverTLS DNSSEC=no/unsupported

Link 3 (wlp0s20f3)
    Current Scopes: DNS LLMNR/IPv4 LLMNR/IPv6
         Protocols: +DefaultRoute LLMNR=resolve -mDNS -DNSOverTLS DNSSEC=no/unsupported
Current DNS Server: 192.168.15.153
       DNS Servers: 192.168.15.153

Link 4 (br-236f66aa6691)
    Current Scopes: none
         Protocols: -DefaultRoute -LLMNR -mDNS -DNSOverTLS DNSSEC=no/unsupported

Link 5 (docker0)
    Current Scopes: none
         Protocols: -DefaultRoute LLMNR=resolve -mDNS -DNSOverTLS DNSSEC=no/unsupported

Link 16 (ipsec0)
    Current Scopes: LLMNR/IPv4 LLMNR/IPv6
         Protocols: -DefaultRoute LLMNR=resolve -mDNS -DNSOverTLS DNSSEC=no/unsupported

Link 17 (vboxnet0)
    Current Scopes: none
         Protocols: -DefaultRoute LLMNR=resolve -mDNS -DNSOverTLS DNSSEC=no/unsupported

Link 18 (br-288fd084c2f1)
    Current Scopes: LLMNR/IPv4 LLMNR/IPv6
         Protocols: -DefaultRoute LLMNR=resolve -mDNS -DNSOverTLS DNSSEC=no/unsupported

Link 22 (veth9f99f5c)
    Current Scopes: LLMNR/IPv6
         Protocols: -DefaultRoute LLMNR=resolve -mDNS -DNSOverTLS DNSSEC=no/unsupported
```

its configuration is unchanged.
but if I add minikube IP in `/etc/systemd/resolved.conf` as DNS, it works! but ofc the other dns are not resolving anymore.

I should mention that I just did not do the `Linux OS with resolvconf`  section as Fedora is using systemd-resolved. Is that the reason why?